# How To Improve PHP and JQuery Code in this Project - only fade out elements that need refreshed instead of whole section?

Tags: php, jquery, refactoring

I came across this website and was impressed by it and wanted to try and learn how it works: http://demo.pellegrom.me/uptime/

My attempt is here: http://www.4playtheband.co.uk/up/up.php but I have had to fade out the entire section rather than just the status'. My tooltips are also broken because they are dynamically generated - I'm sure I need to apply the `live` function but just not sure on how to do this without breaking it.

Here is the code:

up.php:

```
<?php
require('../db.php');
?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#container").load("response.php").fadeIn("slow");

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#container').fadeOut('slow').load('response.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 3600000);

    $('.icon').each(function(){
        $(this).simpletip({
            showEffect: 'fade',
            hideEffect: 'fade',
            fixed: 'true',
            position: 'right',
            offset:[10, 0],
            content: $('img',this).attr('alt')
        });
    });

    $('#check').click(function(){
        $('.http-status').empty();
        $('.http-status').html('<img src="images/spinner.gif"/>');

        $('#container').fadeOut('slow').load('response.php').fadeIn("slow");
    });

});
</script>

<h2>Website Checker</h2>    

<div id="container"></div>

<br /> 
<a href="#" id="check" class="button">Check Now</a>
```

process.php:

```
<?php
require('../db.php');

function Visit($url)
{
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";$ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $page=curl_exec($ch);

    //echo curl_error($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) 
    {
        echo '<span class="up">'.$httpcode.'<span class="icon"><img src="images/info.png" alt="website is up"/></span></span>';
    }
    else
    {
        $httpcode=404;
        echo '<span class="down">'.$httpcode.'<span class="icon"><img src="images/info.png" alt="website is down"/></span></span>';

        $date = date("l, j \of F Y \@ H:i");

        $to      = "someone@domain.com";
        $subject = "Urgent: $url is down";
        $message = "Hello,\n\nIt appears that on our latest check of $url on $date that the site was down.\n\nRegards,\nWeb Checker";
        $headers = 'From: noreply@webchecker.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: noreply@webchecker.co.uk' . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
?>

<ul id="site-list" class="list"> 
    <li class="title">
        <span class="id"></span>
        <span class="name">Title</span>
        <span class="url">URL</span>
        <span class="status">HTTP Status</span>
    </li> 

<?php
// some PHP to fetch all the gig entries from the shows table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `check`";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
// a loop to place all the values in the appropriate table cells
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    //begin the loop...
    $id=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $url=$row['url'];
?>
    <li>
        <span class="id"><?php echo $id; ?></span>
        <span class="name"><?php echo $name; ?></span> 
        <span class="url"><?php echo $url; ?></span>
        <span class="status http-status"><?php echo Visit("$url"); ?></span>
    </li>

<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

That's quite a lot of code, apologies if it's difficult to follow.

Aside from the two points already mentioned, the only other thing puzzling me is how to avoid the e-mail sending when `container` is first loaded upon the page being visited?

Thanks in advance for all help and suggestions.

Comment: if you are going to down vote and ask for it to be closed then please comment so that I may address your grievances with the question.

Comment: I don't feel like reading all that so i m just gonna ask, have you considered AJAX? In simplest terms, you can just echo back individual results and just replace content within status `.http-status` tags so everything else stays as is. I can provide details on this if you are interested.

Comment: Hi Tumharyyaaden, thanks for the comment. If you are able to explain then that would be great - I know how to process forms using jquery's ajax function but I don't know how to do it in this situation since it is not a form. All I need to do is somehow refresh the data within 'http-status', i.e. to call the php function again inside that `span` element, rather than the entire section which is what I am doing at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and AJAX will help you do just that, however, i have to hit the road to home right now but i will comeback and finish my ans below. sorry, please don't vote down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the Ajax since you last looked at, as well as modify other code a little. Like returns in php and loading gif for html and rest of ajax. Hope this helps! when you comment, you should include '@'+'tumharyyaaden' so that stackexchange shows me update, if you have questions ofc.

PHP: save as process.php

```
<?php
require('../db.php');

$url= NULL;
if(isset($_POST['a'])) {    $url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a']);   }

function Visit($url)
{
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";$ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $page=curl_exec($ch);

    //echo curl_error($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) 
    {
        echo '<span class="up">'.$httpcode.'<span class="icon"><img src="images/info.png" alt="website is up"/></span></span>'; exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $httpcode=404;

        $date = date("l, j \of F Y \@ H:i");

        $to      = "someone@domain.com";
        $subject = "Urgent: $url is down";
        $message = "Hello,\n\nIt appears that on our latest check of $url on $date that the site was down.\n\nRegards,\nWeb Checker";
        $headers = 'From: noreply@webchecker.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: noreply@webchecker.co.uk' . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo '<span class="down">'.$httpcode.'<span class="icon"><img src="images/info.png" alt="website is down"/></span></span>'; exit;
    }
}

if(!empty($url)){ Visit($url); exit; } 

?>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="site-list" class="list"> 
    <li class="title">
        <span class="id"></span>
        <span class="name">Title</span>
        <span class="url">URL</span>
        <span class="status">HTTP Status</span>
    </li> 
<?php
// some PHP to fetch all the gig entries from the shows table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `check`";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
// a loop to place all the values in the appropriate table cells
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    //begin the loop...
    $id=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $url=$row['url'];
?>
    <li class="websites">
        <span class="id"><?php echo $id; ?></span>
        <span class="name"><?php echo $name; ?></span> 
        <span class="url"><?php echo $url; ?></span>
        <span class="status http-status"><img src="images/spinner.gif"/></span>
    </li>

<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<br /> 
<a href="#" id="check" class="button">Check Now</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#check').click(function(){

    $('.http-status').html('<img src="images/spinner.gif"/>');

    $('#site-list li.websites').each(function(){
        var newurl = $(this).find('span.url a').attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
            url:     "process.php",
            data:    ({"a":newurl}),
            cache:   false,
            success: function(message){
                $(this).find('li.status').html(message);
            } //End AJAX return
        }); //End AJAX call
    }); //End li each
}); //End Check

$('#check').click();
```

Explanation: Sorry i didn't get to comment the code, but basically, three pieces to it, two php's one that will generate the html, one that will check and return status and last bit is JS which will send requests via AJAX so your page doesn't have to refresh on every check click.

UPDATE: 2011/08/25

It seems odd to me that your current code (namely JS) doesn't resemble anything of what i provided. What i have above is entire construct of your page. So i would say consider adopting at least the JS from above and modifying it to fit your other needs rather than to try and fix your current code which i would say has too many things wrong with it. Anyhow, lets look at your code:

**Your code**

```
$('#check').click(function(){

    $('#site-list li').each(function(){
        var li=$(this);
        if(!li.hasClass('title'))
        {
            $('span.status',li).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" />');

            $.post('process.php',{
            url:$('span.url',li).text(),
            id:$('span.id',li).text()},
            function(response)
            {
                $('span.status',li).html(response.data);
                $('span.status',li).simpletip({fixed:true,position:'right',offset:[5,0],content:response.message});
                var tooltip=$('span.up',li).eq(0).simpletip();

                if(response.up){
                    $('span.up img',li).attr('src','images/activity_monitor.png');
                    tooltip.update('Site is Up');}
                else{
                    $('span.up img',li).attr('src','images/activity_monitor_warning.png');tooltip.update('Site is Down');$('span.status span',li).css('color','red');
                }
            },'json');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So, first, 1). you are missing the `$('#check').click();` which currently prevents loading or the status from showing up properly on page load. Meaning, that bit of code is not optional for you.

Second 2). Your selectors and process of selecting are very inefficient.

```
$('#site-list li').each(function(){
        var li=$(this);
        if(!li.hasClass('title'))
        {
```

Above, your first selector should have been `$('#site-list li.websites').each(` so you wouldn't need to run unnecessary checks on Title class list nor will have to run second check separately on excluding the title class for entire list. When doing these sorts of inefficient checks under `each()` it causes so many unnecessary calls that shouldn't made.

Third 3). You are unnecessarily complicating the script by using your selector style, choice of tooltip plug-in and by using .post instead of .ajax. For tooltip, use something like tiptip tooltip, it's light weight, very easy to use but customizable, full of features and will vastly simplify your script. .ajax is cleaner, more transparent and easier hence reduces potential for conflicts. Also, use actual CSS styles and properties for formatting document, not JS. So again, I like the code that's cleaner, simpler, more transparent and most of all, more efficient, so again, if you need help customizing my code to your needs, i can help. But as your code currently stands, i can not say which part is wrong since too much seems wrong to me.

Forth 4). I don't mean to be rude or to offend you but personally i can not stand the way the current JS code stands. So please don't take this personally, it's just matter of preference more than anything else. That said, i can help you in changing my original answer to better suit your needs.

Comment: thanks, got the files uploaded and ready to go, I assume all that needs completed is the `$.ajax` function?

Comment: Got it, please double check code for typos, i didn't get to test the code, but should work!

Comment: thank @Tumharyyaaden! I will give this a go just now and hopefully I can get it to work. Much appreciated!

Comment: it almost works - when the page loads the spinner shows and clicking the check button just keeps the spinner there too. I think the only thing missing is that it's not passing the `url` parameter through to process.php

Comment: Add `alert(newurl);` under JS bit, and see what you get, I double checked the selector and it's working find, you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/aszqg/ The only thing that would be a problem is that where you have `<?php echo $url; ?>` if your links are not constructed as `<span class='url'><a href='website.com'>website.com</a></span>` then it wouldn't work, so if in fact it is just `<span class='url'>website.com</span>` then change the `var newurl = $(this).find('span.url').html();` which will grab the content of span which is complete URL. Meaning your $url is just website name and

Comment: not entire html link tag as `$url = '<a href="website.com">website.com</a>';` which is better to save as var anyways, you would need to change the html part above to match or js to match so you can change either of the three to fix the problem.

Comment: thanks for you help, I will try out your suggestions. I will definitely accept your answer just as soon as I've messed around and got it to work so hopefully it's soon!

Comment: hmm. You are right about the url, I was just printing out a string, not an actual link. I changed the js accordingly to `var newurl = $(this).find('span.url').html();`. I also removed the spinner from `.http-status` upon page load and when I click 'Check Now' the html isn't being changed to show the spinner! Very weird, must be a tiny mistake somewhere. http://4playtheband.co.uk/check/#

Comment: Hi - sorry, I didn't see your updated post! I changed it because I was messing around trying to get it to work. I have update the code now but changed `newurl` to be `var newurl = $(this).find('span.url').html();` like you suggested because the url span is just text and is not an actual link.

I also changed the html so that the spinner isn't there upon first loading the page but only when you click the button but looking at it now, the click function doesn't seem to do anything at all and I can't see why not!

Comment: seems to almost work if I put the jquery inside a document.ready function - the post and response are correct but it isn't echoed out correctly, the spinner just stays there without being replaced.

Comment: @ Tumharyyaaden - I also changed the ajax return to look like this as I thought it would work but still no joy on actually getting it to display `$(this).find('span.http-status').html(message);`

Comment: Sorry, was on vac, didn't see this post till today, but i see you have accepted the ans, but also may have pending issues, so just bring me to speed and i'll try to post asap...

Comment: Hi @Tumharyyaaden, hope you had a good holiday. I got it to work so would just like to say thanks for all your help, I hope to see you around SO in the future.